# Why does the sign of the result determine the location of the point?

Tags: linear-algebra, coordinate-systems

I had learned this in school:- if we have an equation of a line (say `x+y-6=0`) if the result from substituting a point comes out to be:

1. negative = then the point is above the line
2. positive = then the point is below the line

So If I put in the point `(3,2)`, then it would be `3+2-6 = -1 = negative = point above the line`.

I attempted to prove it but wasn't able to think of any theorems/logic that can aid this.

> Can anyone explain the proof or any logic that explains why this works??
> Or is this determined experimentally?

Example:
[image: An example I randomly tried]

Comment: fyi $(3,2)$ is below the line $x+y-6=0$.

Comment: But the equation of the line can be multiplied by $-1$ without changing the line. And that would cause the sign obtained by substituting coordinates to switch. And so the point doesn't determine the sign. One would need to specify which equation is used for the line somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easily understood from a continuity argument.

The line is the locus of the points of coordinates such that $f(x,y)=ax+by+c=0$. By continuity (Intermediate Value theorem), you cannot move from a point where $f$ is positive to a point where it is negative without crossing the line. Hence the line splits the plane by sign.

(For a more correct description, you should replace "above" and "below" by "left" and "right", where the orientation depends on the signs of the coefficients.)

Comment: Your explanation was very helpful, however, I was unable to understand it :( Can you elaborate more on it in simpler words?

Comment: I was referring to the explanation about the locus and the Intermediate Value Thereom

Comment: yes. but not the part about "continuity"

Comment: @neelg: do you understand the term "continuity" ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119010/discussion-between-neel-g-and-yves-daoust).

Answer (score 0):

This is not true.

[image]

The above graph shows the lines $x+y-6=0$ and $-x-y-6=0$. If we put in $(3,2)$ into each of the lines, we get $$3+2-6=-1<0$$ and $$-3-2-6=-11<0$$ respectively. Both give a negative result, but the point is below the first line and above the second.

Comment: Your second equation is wrong, it would be `+6` not `-6`

Comment: @neelg why? i wasn't trying to make it the same line